# How to clone or copy mongodb collection through javascript command not from cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

As I know how to clone the MongoDB collection by typing the command on cmd.
As I want to do clone through javascript which will be running through cron job on nodejs environment.

```
Like on my app.js file I am calling the file like this
var Message = require('./models/copymessage');
```

what I would like is like this

```
var CopyCollection = new CronJob('00 36 17 * * *', function() {
    //Some command which can copy the collection.
    //I am using MongoDB 3.0+ version
}, null, true, 'Asia/Kolkata');
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to copy a collection within the same MongoDB instance

There is an implementation that I use. You can skip the lines with indexes if you don't want to copy it.

```
function copyCollection(from, to) {
    db.getCollection(from).aggregate([ { $out: to } ])
    db.getCollection(from).getIndexes().forEach(function(inx) {
         db.getCollection(to).createIndex(inx.key);
    })
    var newCollectionDocuments = db.getCollection(to).count()
    var newCollectionIndexes = db.getCollection(to).getIndexes()
    print("Document inserted: " + newCollectionDocuments)
    print("Indexes: " + tojson(newCollectionIndexes))
}
```